# Magento 2.1: How to get Product attributes in overridden LayoutProcessor.php

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, blocks, shipping-methods, zipcode

I want to hide the "Zip/Postal Code" region in the summary Block in the cart page.I overwrote the block file LayoutProcessor.php. In that file, if I hid the following portion from the function process, then I would be able to hide the "Zip/Postal Code".

```
'postcode' => [
            'visible' => true,
            'formElement' => 'input',
            'label' => __('Zip/Postal Code'),
            'value' => null
        ]
```

I want to check the attributes of the products in the cart. If any of the products has the attribute value 'No', then hide the "Zip/Postal Code" and instead show an error message. How can I add the condition in LayoutProcessor.php to hide the same based on the attributes of the products on the cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following lines in the function. The $cartData will provide you the products

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productObject = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    $cartObject = $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
    $cartData = $cartObject->getQuote()->getAllItems();
```

Then Please loop through the $cartData and use the following code in the loop

```
foreach ($cartData as $item) {
        $product = $productObject->load($item->getProduct()->getId());
        $attr = $product->getAttributeText('attribute_you_want') ;
        /*conditions u need*/
}
```

Add the 'if' condition to hide the part u need to.